# Find unique values from find

Tags: find, csh

I want to find unique files inside a directory, which also have sub directories.

There are specific types of files, say `.lib` files.

There are same `.lib` file inside different sub directoris. I need to find the list of `.lib` files inside my home directory, but only unique names. Are there any method to do so ?

Currently I am using

```
find -name "*.lib" > lib_file_list
```

But it gives duplicate results as some of the `.lib` files are in multiple sub directories. I am using CSH.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With GNU tools:

```
find . -name '*.lib' -print0 | awk -v RS='\0' -F/ '! seen[$NF]++'
```

Comment: This gives me the error `seen[: Event not found` error

Comment: @ThisaruGuruge, sorry forgot about that other idiosyncrasy of `csh`. See `edit`.

Comment: BTW: `find … -printf '%f\0'` should give just the file names, null-separated, with GNU find.

Comment: @derobert, yes, but AFAICT, the OP stills wants the full path (one path if there are several paths with the same name) to be printed.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. 

@derobert Can you explain this. I think it's better to avoid the full path, but adding `-print '%f\0'` gives me `find: paths must precede expression: \%f\0` error.

Comment: @ThisaruGuruge, that's `-printf`, not `-print`. For the `./path/to/foo.lib` file, `-printf '%f\0'` prints `foo.lib<NUL>` as opposed to `./path/to/foo.lib<NUL>` with `-print0`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would do:

```
find -name '*.lib' -printf '%f\n' | sort | uniq > lib_file_list
```

A few things to keep in mind:

- this won't give you the full paths of the files (I assume this doesn't
  matter since your question requires elimination of some paths anyway)
- it will fail if you have newlines in any of your filenames
- and of course assuming GNU tools.

Comment: cool (+1) ... or `sort -u`

Comment: Or `-printf '%f\0' | sort -zu | tr '\0' '\n'`